# How to REALLY disable re-indent on paste

Tags: python, atom-editor

I'm using Atom at work for editing Python code, and I'm running against a painful interaction between muscle memory and a labor-saving feature.

Near as I can tell, Atom will, when you paste a snippet of code, redo the indentation so that it's consistent with the indentation of the line it was pasted into, preserving relative indents.

If I didn't have any baggage from using editors *without* this feature, I'm pretty sure it'd be great, but as it is, I can't break my habit of selecting back to the preceding newline, and pasting that, which tends to do crazy things when pasting to or from the first line of a block.

I've tried to turn off Auto Indent on Paste, but it's not on anywhere I can find, and I'm not even sure it's the same feature; it's just what I hear about from people complaining about Atom going crazy when they paste Python.

So, where do I look to disable this? I'm willing to work up from no extensions back to what I've got installed, so assume a vanilla install.

I guess the workflow I'm looking for is "paste, manual re-indent", because at least that way I know what I'm getting and my response is always the same. As it stands, I don't have to think about it until it converts simple line rearrangements into syntactic garbage, which is *worse* than just adjusting things every time.

EDIT: In response to Milo Price, I have just now tried setting both `autoIndentOnPaste` and `normalizeIndentOnPaste` to `false`. The behavior is unchanged.

FURTHER EDIT: I had to reload the configuration for it to take. It's working now.

Comment: Have you set both `autoIndentOnPaste` and `normalizeIndentOnPaste` to false?

Comment: That fixed it, thanks @MiloPrice!

Comment: Great! I'll repost it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the config options `autoIndentOnPaste` and `normalizeIndentOnPaste` both to `false`, and then reload the configuration.